# Elasticsearch data representation

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

I am new to elasticsearch and I thought I will go through the [10 minutes walk through](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/kibana/current/using-kibana-for-the-first-time.html) to get started.
But I stumbled upon with some very basic doubts here. I am not able to figure out the data representation here. For eg. the tutorial mentions about creating an index

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/shakespeare -d '
{
 "mappings" : {
  "_default_" : {
   "properties" : {
    "speaker" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
    "play_name" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
    "line_id" : { "type" : "integer" },
    "speech_number" : { "type" : "integer" }
   }
  }
 }
}
';
```

I understand that this is a JSON string, but beyond that I am not able to understand this representation? I am not getting what is *default*, what is meant by not_analyzed and so on.

Is there any standard that needs to be understood on how the data is represented before proceeding with elasticsearch?
I am totally new to elasticsearch and would really appreciate if I am guided with some information/tutorial which would help me understand how to start learning this technology.

Thanks & Regards
Sunil

Comment: :-) please, read the documentation. There is a book available on the ES website (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html) which is really really good. It's long, but after reading it, you'll understand much better what Elasticsearch is and what can it do for you. If you plan on using Elasticsearch seriously, read the book!

Comment: Thank you. I should have started with the book at the first place..:)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the main aim of the [10 minutes walk through](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/kibana/current/using-kibana-for-the-first-time.html#using-kibana-for-the-first-time) is to give a quick demo about Kibana and not a full understanding of elasticsearch (mapping,indexing,etc.)

But if you wish to understand what's happening in that example, you might want to know how to go through the documentation.

Example :

**default mapping :**

```
Often, all types in an index share similar fields and settings. 
It can be more convenient to specify these common settings in 
the _default_ mapping, instead of having to repeat yourself every 
time you create a new type. The _default_ mapping acts as a 
template for new types. All types created after the _default_ 
mapping will include all of these default settings, unless 
explicitly overridden in the type mapping itself.
```

And for more details about *default mapping*, please refer [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/default-mapping.html).

Answer (score 1):

The 10 minute walk-thru is for Kibana, running on top of Elasticsearch, and IMHO is not a great place to start when getting to know ES.

Personally over the last few years I've these introductions to be helpful:

http://joelabrahamsson.com/elasticsearch-101/

http://exploringelasticsearch.com/overview.html

Overall the ES documentation is reasonably complete, looks great but can be hard to navigate thru for a novice to find exactly what you need.